# I have developed an application using RPGLE and CL languages in as400, what should be my installation plan on client's IBM i OS

Tags: installation, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have built an application on AS400 system, as a professional developer what should be my approach towards installation of my application  on client's system.
My questions are

1. Can i replicate my installation like how we install PTF's on AS400 OS.
2. How does anyone who developed any application on As400 install/deploy their application on client's server.

Note: i have used SAVE File to send the object to other as400 server, but what i what to do is something more professional ( like PTF's installation )

Comment: That's an interesting question but that's not really a programming question. So SO is not the best place to ask I think (maybe mcpressonline or code400)

Comment: If you really want to create a product like IBM does, you have a bunch of APIs to help [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/sw1.htm), but maybe it's to much if you're alone

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type of application you've developed here. Is that a web based application? which needs HTTP instance to be configured and require websphere JVM running. If not you can restore the packages from savefile using RSTOBJ and then start using the applications using Greenscreen menu's.